# Tableau rest api user information

Tags: rest, tableau-api

Is it possible to get the user language settings from a tableau server via rest api.

I found this (link below), but the response does not contain any language-info (e.g. DE, EN...)

https://onlinehelp.tableau.com/v2018.1/api/rest_api/en-us/help.htm#REST/rest_api_ref.htm#Query_User_On_Site%3FTocPath%3DAPI%2520Reference%7C_____70

thx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately, it is not possible today.

Comment: yep, unfortunately